# Bash Script Failure - Regular Expression

Tags: regex, bash

I have code with expression where i am trying to enforce the branching Naming convention

```
valid_branch_regex="^(feature|bugfix|release|hotfix)([-\d-]+)([a-z]+$)"
```

Valid Case : Feature-1231-SomeName

Invalid Case : Feature-SomeName-1223 | SomeName-232-Feature

but not able to execute this with bash script , Every time its failing with Invalid Case even for the correct inputs .

Bash Version : 3.182.0

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
LC_ALL=C
#local_branch="$(Build.SourceBranchName)"
shopt -s nocasematch
local_branch="Feature-92784-PlotBreakingFix"
valid_branch_regex="^(feature|bugfix|release|hotfix)([-\d-]+)([a-z]+$)"
message="There is something wrong with your branch name. Branch names in this project must adhere to this contract: $valid_branch_regex. Your commit will be rejected. You should rename your branch to a valid name and try again."
if [[  $local_branch =~ $valid_branch_regex ]];
then
    echo "Branch Name: $local_branch"
    echo "Status:Valid"
    shopt -u nocasematch
    exit 0
else
    echo "Branch Name: $local_branch"
    echo "Error: $message"
    shopt -u nocasematch
    exit 1
fi
```

Comment: bash regex doesn't support `\d`. Use `[0-9]` or `[[:digit:]]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is valid Regex as @Anubhava suggested

```
^(feature|bugfix|release|hotfix)(-)([0-9]+)(-)([a-z]+$)
```